# How can I protect my WorPress website from abusing?

Tags: wordpress

I want to build a website with WordPress for a company which sells reports weekly to their subscribers. Now they want to have a website that each client can not give the username and password to the others and the strangers cannot uses their website freely!

what can I do??

They want only the subscribers which paid the membership can use their website not the strangers.

one seclusion can be the session. I mean we can give only username and password run time; when a person is online with one username and password another person with this username and pass can not use it.

Do you have another solution??

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress session tokens](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_session_tokens/) work pretty neat, and is fairly safe and easy solution to use. If you're not a fan of the session solution, you can always use a 2-step authentication. This will make certain that the user that's logging in is the actual user logging in. A combination of those two would probably even be more ideal.